# Cloud Functions for Firebase FCM Notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

How to use two events triggered to send a single notification in firebase cloud functions, As one event is firebase default didn't contains email or fcmtoken to send notification or email ! Can i pick email for the user from other event?

Answer (score 0):

If your event is triggered by the user you would like to send a notification to, you can use the event to get the authenticated user's uid to retrieve their email address.

```
let uid = event.auth.variable.uid;

admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```